# how to save simple image in pillow-python without any change in quality?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'd like to store an image with the exact copy as the original without any change in quality,

When i set `quality=100` in Pillow Python, The saved image has **5kB less** space than the originial

How do i retain the size? I'm retreiving the image from streams

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

image = Image.open("image.jpg")
file_path = io.BytesIO();
image.save(file_path,'JPEG',quality=100);
file_path.seek(0);

image2 = Image.open(file_path)


image2.save("image_copy2.jpg",'JPEG');
```

Comment: So why just not to make a copy of an image, like you would do normally when making copies of files?

Comment: You might google "jpeg degradation" to see why this is a bad idea, then consider Marcin's approach since it doesn't look like you're making any modifications to it.

Answer (score 1):

Save the image with 100% quality. This will still save the image slightly different from the original, because it will also use subsampling to reduce the image size.

```
img.save('test.jpg', quality=100)
```

You can also turn off subsampling to make sure you get the exact same as the original image.

```
img.save('test.jpg', quality=100, subsampling=0)
```

Comment: This is incorrect. If you want to make an exact copy of the image, you should use `shutil.copyfile`. If you want to make *"best effort, nearest"* copy, you should use `img.save(..., quality='keep')`

Comment: Source https://jdhao.github.io/2019/07/20/pil_jpeg_image_quality/